# How to write a search in R which matches columns from different tables and returns another column from the first table?

Tags: r

```
Table_1

Name    Age    City           Mobile
John S  40    New York        444444
Roy M   24    London          999999
Smith   30    Venice          444555

Table_2
Name      Age   Gender
John S    40      M
Susane    28      F
```

What will be the code to match columns from Table_1 Name, Age and Table_2 Name,Age and return Mobile from Table_1.

Comment: Use the `merge` or `match`

Comment: You should determine data structures which are used by you at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` from base R, or use `left_join` from `library(dplyr)`

```
library(dplyr)

Table_3 <- Table_2 %>% left_join(Table_1, by = c("Name", "Age"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge` and join your two data frames on the `Name` and `Age` columns.

```
result <- merge(Table_1, Table_2,by=c("Name", "Age"))
result
    Name Age     City Mobile Gender
1 John S  40 New York 444444      M
```

Note that the default values for `all.x` and `all.y` are false, which is what we want here.  We want an inner join between the two data frames, i.e. in the result a row should only appear if the name and age also appeared in both data frames.

### Demo